# media querie manager en sass

Tags: html5, css3, sass, mediaqueries

Tengo un problema con los *media queries* y *SASS*. Armé la fórmula del ***media querie manager***, pero **Google Chrome** no me lo toma. Aclaro que no probé en otro navegador.

Tengo el código así:

```
@mixin respond ($breakpoint){

  @if $breakpoint == phone{
      @media only screen and (max-with: 37.5em) { @content };
  } //si el breakpoint dice phone pasa lo que dice el mixin
  @if $breakpoint == tab-port{
      @media only screen and (max-with: 56.25em) { @content };
  }
  @if $breakpoint == tab-land{
      @media only screen and (max-with: 75em) { @content };
  }
  @if $breakpoint == big-desktop{
      @media only screen and (min-with: 112.5em) { @content };
  }    
}
```

Y después tengo los primeros *media queries* así:

```
html
{
    font-size: 62.5%;

    @include respond(big-desktop) {
        font-size: 90%; //1 rem = 12px, 9/16 =56.25%
    }

    @include respond(tab-land) {
        font-size: 56.25%; //1 rem = 9px, 9/16 =56.25%
    }

    @include respond(tab-port) {
        font-size: 50%; //1 rem = 8px, 8/16 =50%
    }

    @include respond(phone) {
        font-size: 31.25%; //1 rem = 5px, 5/16 =%
    }

}
```

Además, tengo en el `meta` lo siguiente:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

No entiendo dónde está el error, si alguien puede darme una mano le estaría totalmente agradecido.

Comment: hola David, probé con pixeles también y no me lo toma. de hecho cuando abro la página en el navegador y busco el archivo main.css y están los media pero no me los toma

Comment: Decidí eliminar el comentario anterior y colocar una respuesta, ya que era indiferente el uso de `em` de `px`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Media Queries

No funcionó porque se utilizó `max-with` en lugar de `max-width`, ya que la primera es una *Media features* no válida.

Aquí la solución al problema *Media Queries*:

```
@mixin respond ($breakpoint) {

  @if $breakpoint == phone {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 37.5em) { @content };
  }

  @if $breakpoint == tab-port {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 56.25em) { @content };
  }

  @if $breakpoint == tab-land {
      @media only screen and (max-width: 75em) { @content };
  }

  @if $breakpoint == big-desktop {
      @media only screen and (min-width: 112.5em) { @content };
  }  

}
```

Aquí su utilización:

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;

    @include respond(big-desktop) {
        font-size: 90%;
    }

    @include respond(tab-land) {
        font-size: 56.25%;
    }

    @include respond(tab-port) {
        font-size: 50%;
    }

    @include respond(phone) {
        font-size: 31.25%;
    }

}
```

Puede ampliar en [Media Queries Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-3/) o [Media Queries - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

Comment: Genio! muchísimas gracias